# Why executable jar file produced from netbeans doesn't work as I run project from Netbeans itslef?

Tags: java, netbeans

Please i work in java project to convert pdf to epub, the project work good from netbeanse but when i run project from jar file(produced from netbeans)it doesn't work good,why?

Comment: "Why?" Because you made a mistake ... I know, this answer isn't helpful, neither is your problem description.

Comment: Work 'good'? What happens? What's the issue? This question doesn't really help anybody.

Comment: If there are mistake,project not run from netbeans?? but it is work good without problems

Comment: Ok,let's me explain the problem more,
I work in project to convert pdf to epub, the problem come with arabic pdf files, english books converted successfully, but arabic books converted with problems in fonts although it is converted good with Netbeans but not with jar file!!!, why??

Comment: Get you any error message when fail ? Try to run jar from command line to see any output: `java -jar myjar.jar`

Comment: no any errors, only the output is different!!!!!

Comment: Do not use multiple exclamation/question marks. We are "hard working" on your problem, we don't need more pressure ;-)

Comment: Can you give us more information ? You get some output but it is not the expected. Give us a small example of input, output and what you have expected to get.

Comment: I am sorry Mr PeterMmm, i can't solve the problem , i don't know the reason and its urgent for me, apologize me
i will give you sample diffrent output from netbeans and jar file

Comment: the project: convert pdf to html
input: arabic pdf(problem occured with arabic books only)
output from netbeans(right output):
<html>
<DIV id='div1' STYLE='position: absolute;LEFT:128.95683px;TOP:354.53522px;font-size:13.0px;font-family:XONZMS+QCF_P028;'><SPAN>ﯓ </SPAN></DIV>
</html>
------------
output from jar:
<DIV id='div1' STYLE='position: absolute;LEFT:128.95683px;TOP:354.53522px;font-size:13.0px;font-family:XONZMS+QCF_P028;'><SPAN>? </SPAN></DIV>

Hint: first output get me the arabic character
second output get me question mark '?' not the character itself
i hope to led me to sol,thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start your jar with the additional argument `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Comment: please write me the complete command assume jar file named "test.jar"

Comment: That should be `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar test.jar`

Comment: Very very thanks Mr Ben and Mr PeterMmm for your excellent help, i tried to run jar file with this command and give me the output i need.
I don't know what this command do to correct the output but the important that it is solved, Many thanks for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are writing PDF text to HTML. You should know what encoding is written into the HTML file and advice client browser about this:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Or as alternative try to change the character encoding in the browser.

The `?` means that you are going to visualize data but the visualization program don't know about the
encoding or uses an encoding that has no character at that code point.